# How to call a specific subroutine of an AppleScript from another AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I understand that it is possible to trigger an .scpt file that is saved somewhere on my computer from within a different .scpt file.

Can I call a specific subroutine of that .scpt file from a different .scpt file? I want to skip over the entire script, and only run the code that is found in one, specific subroutine

I understand that I can simply copy the subroutine into its own, dedicated .scpt file and accomplish what I want that way. This method is demonstrated in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135271/in-an-applescript-how-do-i-call-reuse-a-subroutine-from-another-applescript/135289#135289). However, I would prefer not to have to do this, for the sake of convenience.

---

In addition, is it possible to also pass variables to that subroutine? My current need does not require this ability, but I am still curious.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## AppleScript's `load script`

AppleScript's [`load script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW35) command will do what you want.

### Example

On your Desktop, save a `.scpt` file containing the following `saySomething` handler:

```
on saySomething()
    say "hello"
end saySomething
```

Then within another script you can call `saySomething`:

```
set myOtherScript to load script (alias ((path to desktop folder as string) & "external.scpt"))
myOtherScript's saySomething()
```

The returned object from `load script` is a script object. Once loaded, the script object is treated as local and can have its local [handles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH) called, including with parameters.

See [Can I put shared applescript code in a separate file and load it in various scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267426/can-i-put-shared-applescript-code-in-a-separate-file-and-load-it-in-various-scri) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions in your OP...

- > The Title: How to call a specific subroutine of an AppleScript from another AppleScript?

  This is actually answered by the link, within the linked answer, in your OP and also touched on by Graham Miln's answer.
- > Can I call a specific subroutine of that .scpt file from a different .scpt file? I want to skip over the entire script, and only run the code that is found in one, specific subroutine.

  This is the good question because the documentation and examples focus on the *handlers* themselves and tend to show that external scripts being called should just be a collection of *handlers* and no other AppleScript *code*.

  Well, as an old saying goes... proof is in the pudding... The answer is yes, you can call a *handler* from another *filename.scpt* file that contains any valid AppleScript *code*. **Note that the target of the `load script` *command* will load the entire *script* to memory however, will not execute anything other then the *handler(s)* called.**
- > In addition, is it possible to also pass variables to that subroutine?

  Providing the *handler* being called is written to take *parameters*, then yes you can pass it a *variable* that has already been assigned and pass it as a *parameter*.